# java.lang.Error at bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge.invoke using Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Got a lot of errors like this one in my Google Play Developer console (only on Android 8.0 and above), so my crash rate raises very quickly. Using Unity 5.3.8p2. Anyone can help?

```
at bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge.invoke (Native Method)
at bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a.invoke (Unknown Source:20)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke (Proxy.java:913)
at $Proxy0.onBindingDied (Unknown Source)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1654)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1687)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```